# How to use both open source and proprietary video drivers on same machine?

Tags: package-management, graphics

On my main work machine I sometimes need to use the proprietary Nvidia video drivers, but I would prefer to use the open source Nouveau drivers most of the time. As the Nvidia package conflicts with the Nouveau package (at least on Arch), this cannot be done easily. Basically, I want to nearly identical installations that only differ on which of the two packages (and their dependencies) are installed and a couple of XOrg configuration files. Is this possible without having to maintain two separate systems?

Comment: Maybe download the PKGBUILD for one of those packages, and change it so that the packages don’t conflict.